# HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found when reading external js and css file in Shiny python

Tags: javascript, python, webassembly, starlette, py-shiny

##### Issue

This is using Shiny.py, not R Shiny. See [here](https://github.com/posit-dev/py-shiny) for shiny.py repo.

I am getting an error that says `"GET /script.js HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found` . This is when I use `ui.head_content(ui.include_js(js_file))` as per this documentation [here](https://shiny.posit.co/py/api/ui.include_js.html). I am using it alongside `ui.include_css()`.

##### reprex:

app.py

```
from shiny import App, render, ui
from htmltools.tags import div, script
from pathlib import Path

css_file = Path(__file__).parent / "www" / "stylesheet.css"
js_file = Path(__file__).parent / "www" / "script.js"

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.head_content(ui.include_js(js_file)),
    ui.head_content(ui.include_css(css_file)),
    div(
        {"class": "redbkg"},
        ui.h2("Hello Shiny!"),
        ui.input_slider("n", "N", 0, 100, 20),
        ui.output_text_verbatim("txt")
    )
)


def server(input, output, session):
    @output
    @render.text
    def txt():
        return f"n*2 is {input.n() * 2}"


app = App(app_ui, server)
```

stylesheet.css

```
.redbkg{
    background-color: rgb(241, 201, 201);
}
```

script.js

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "skyblue";
```

##### Network reads script.js

I tried a few other things following [this](https://shiny.posit.co/py/docs/ui-styling.html) resource and also using htmltools `script` to replicate how I would normally do it in R (i.e. `script(src="script.js")` after the body). You can see the repo for py-htmltools [here](https://github.com/posit-dev/py-htmltools/blob/main/htmltools/tags.py). However, I keep getting the same error. This might be a broader issue because the css file alone works, but the js file alone doesn't seem to be affecting anything (even though it is being read correctly in the Network).

##### starlette vs wasm?

I noticed in the Shiny py repo there is a [file](https://github.com/posit-dev/py-shiny/blob/6bf5022dc8165aa7746f56b79eb4c0280a02ff39/shiny/http_staticfiles.py#L4) called http_staticfiles.py. In it, it says:

> We can't use starlette's StaticFiles when running in wasm mode,
> because it launches a thread. Instead, use our own crappy version.
> Fortunately, this is all we need.
>
> When running in native Python mode, use the starlette StaticFiles
> impl; it's battle tested, whereas ours is not. Under wasm, it's OK if
> ours has bugs, even security holes: everything is running in the
> browser sandbox including the filesystem, so there's nothing we could
> disclose that an attacker wouldn't already have access to. The same is
> not true when running in native Python, we want to be as safe as
> possible.

I'm wondering if this is a hint to the issue, but not sure how to proceed.

Does anyone have any insight into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug, confirmed by Joe Cheng. The issue is raised on [github](https://github.com/posit-dev/py-shiny/issues/729)

The current workarounds are:

1. put files in separate directories, then add `defer=""` to the `include_js()` call
2. or, add method="inline" to the `include_js()` call.